# How to grep after a certain pattern?

Tags: grep

I have a input file such as

```
file;14;19;;;hello 2019 
file2;2019;2020;;;this is a test 2020
file3;25;31;this is a number 31
```

I would like to grep numbers only after `;;;`. For example if I wanted to grep `2019` it would give me

```
file;14;19;;;hello 2019
```

instead of if I did `grep '2019' file`

```
file;14;19;;;hello 2019 
file2;2019;2020;;;this is a test 2020
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: How about a simple `;;;.*2019` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression can include stuff *other* than fixed text, it sounds like all you need is:

```
grep ';;;.*[0-9]' inputFile.txt
```

This will deliver all lines that have the text `;;;` followed by a digit somewhere after that in the line. In terms of explanation:

- `;;;` is the literal text, three semicolons;
- `.*` is zero or more of any character;
- `[0-9]` is any digit.

That will give you lines with *any* number. If you want a *specific* number, use that for the final bullet point above.

---

Just keep in mind that this will *also* give you the line `xyzzy ;;; 920194` if you go looking for `2019`.

If you want *just* the `2019` numbers (i.e., without any digits on either side), you can use the zero-width negative look-behind and look-ahead assertions, assuming your version of `grep` has Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE, which GNU `grep` does with the `-P` flag):

```
grep -P ';;;.*(?<![0-9])2019(?![0-9])' inputFile.txt
```

This can be read as:

- `;;;` is the literal text, three semicolons;
- `.*` is zero or more of any character;
- `(?<![0-9])` means next match cannot be *preceded* by a digit;
- `2019` is the number you're looking for;
- `(?![0-9])` means previous match cannot be *followed* by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F';' -lane 'print if $F[-1] =~ /2019/' in_file
```

Example:

```
( echo 'file;14;19;;;hello 2019' ; echo 'file2;2019;2020;;;this is a test 2020' ) | perl -F';' -lane 'print if $F[-1] =~ /2019/'
```

Prints:

```
file;14;19;;;hello 2019
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F';'` : Split into `@F` on semicolon (`;`), rather than on whitespace.

`$F[-1]` : the last element of the array `@F` = the last element of the input line split on semicolon. Alternatively, use `$F[5]` (the 6th element - the arrays are 0-indexed), if you need to count from the left.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)